# jQuery: better performance with check whether binding element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder... Let's imagine I have a code something like that:

```
$('#specific-element').change(some_long_and_ajax_function);
```

Element with binded ID doesn't exist on all of my pages. On some of them only. I do check whether this element exists like this:

```
if($('#specific-element').length > 0){
  $('#specific-element').change(some_long_and_ajax_function);
  // There can be more stuff related to this specific element
}
```

My question: is it worth it? Is there any performance impact for binding handlers for non-existing elements or checking length is worse than it? Or is it basically same and I have two useless rows? What would you recommend? The first one keeps code nice and clear but I'm not sure if this will be "healthy" for jQuery with dozens of examples like that. Thanks.

Comment: You can at least cache the jQuery element : if it exists, you have not to recreate the jQuery object (`var $elt = $("#specific-element"); if($elt.length > 0) { $elt.change();}`).

Comment: `$('#specific-element').length` is useless, as jQuery will not bind anything if there are no matches. No big deal. On other hand you make 2 DOM searches when you go with your second version.

Comment: Ok, thank both of you. Since jQuery doesn't bind no match cases, I will delete this checking of exists. And if it is be necessary anyway, I will stick with caching at least, it's good suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery fails gracefully if the element doesn't exist, internally it does it's own check to see if the element exists, and if it doesn't the event handler isn't attached etc.

`jQuery()` calls `jQuery.fn.init` wich checks if the passed argument is a string, which in your case it is, it then calls `jQuery.fn.find` with the right context, and inside that it does

```
var i, ret = [],
    self = this,
    len = self.length;

... code

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // add event handlers
}
```

so the loop never runs if there are no elements to run it on, so there's no need to do your own check, just let jQuery handle it.

**EDIT:**

When you call `$('#specific-element').length` you're already calling `$()`, and it does all the usual things internally and returns an array-like jQuery object that has a length property, and that's exactly what `$('#specific-element').change...` does as well, and jQuery's `on()` also returns rather quickly if no elements exists in the collection, so there really is no difference.

If you're really concerned about speed, you'd do something like

```
var el = document.getElementById('specific-element');

if ( el !== null ) {
    el.addEventListener('change', fn, false);
}
```

but there's really no reason, just add event handler with jQuery the usual way, without checking it the element exists, it's what almost every website in existance does, and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to read deep explanation and much more easy to remember than "just don't do it" is. :)

Comment: I slightly disagree, jquery does check if element exists but if you see how many things it's checks inside. Including a regex in fn.init. Then it goes to jQuery.fn.extend({ part there are a lot of code is executed. You don't have to check existance of element but it's not useless.

Comment: That's true, jQuery does a lot of other things as well, it doesn't just check the length and returns, but when you do `$(element).length` you're also calling `jQuery()` and it does all those things anyway, the only difference is that it now does it twice, once when you check the length, and once when you attach the event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment, jQuery check if the element exist before binding events. But there is a speed difference wether you check or not.

When checking before binding, you save time if the element doesn't exist because getting a property (`.length`) is way faster than calling a function (which will probably call other functions) and failing gracefully.

But if the element exist, it will be slower since you add a condition before binding. Hence, it add 1 more step than if you did not check before and directly binded the event.

Just interpret those test results : http://jsperf.com/check-before-binding<sup>1</sup>

You can see that if the element exist, the difference between the *check before* is only `4000 operations / second` more. It is not a lot... On the other hand, when you check if the element exist and **it doesn't**, it save `1,000,000 operations / second` because it doesn't call the function `.change()`.

## Conclusion

I'd say checking before is better if that really matter, but mostly, it doesn't. If the element is most often present than missing on different pages, i'd directly bind the event. If the element is mostly missing than present, i'd check before binding.

In the end, we are talking about `0.0000001ms`...

<sup>1</sup><sub>I have slightly changed to code to optimise your. Caching the element sure is important is you want better performances.</sub>

Comment: +1 Exactly and it's not 'calling a function' but there are more functions.

Comment: @SSA true, i've added it in the answer! Thank.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I thought performance impact will be little, it was more hypothetic curious question. Fraction of milisecond sounds a negligible but on the other hand... difference is almost three times faster for checking. So I believe it matters in some special application but mine is kinda small webapp. :)

Thanks for your explanation, it's more complicated problem how I see.